# Add taxonomy field to a bundle programmatically

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently developing a module which provides a content type called "Structural machinery" . This type should also provide a taxonomy term based on different manufacturers providing the machine (eg CAT or Komatsu) , I know how to create a taxonomy vocabulary programmatically but the question is how to attach a taxonomy field to my bundle.

this is the code used to implement the taxonomy term :

```
$term = new stdClass();
$term -> name = $t('Manufacture');
$term -> machine_name = 'manufacture';
$term -> description = $t('Description');
$term -> hierarchy = 2;
$term -> module = 'construction_machinery';
$term -> weight = 1;
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($term);
```

Comment: "Salam Dada", Did you create content type programmatically or you have  content type and just want add it programmatically to that content type ? 
or you have content type and a field that referenced to this vocabulary and you just want save the data in it?
Please provide more details about what you want

Comment: @zhilevan "Aleyke Salam dada" , the module provides a new content type and attaches some fields to the content (fields like Engine, Transmission and ... which are implemented using Field API in some other modules) , another property which should be added to provided content type is the builder of the machine that should be saved as a term reference. so every thing is being implemented in hook_install() o the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create your field

```
$field_name = 'field_manufacture';

$field = field_info_field($field_name);
if(!$field){
  $field = array(
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        0 => array(
          'vocabulary' => 'manufacture',
          'parent' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'field_name' => $field_name,
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
    'module' => 'taxonomy',
    'active' => '1',
    'cardinality' => '1',
  );
  field_create_field($field);
}
```

Then create your instance(s)

```
$node_types = array('page','whatever');
foreach($node_types as $type){

  $instance = field_info_instance('node',$field_name,$type);
  if(!$instance){
    $instance = array(
      'label' => 'Manufacture',
      'widget' => 
      array(
        'weight' => 3,
        'type' => 'options_select',
        'module' => 'options',
        'active' => 1,
      ),
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => $type,
    );

    field_create_instance($instance);
  }

}
```

if you do var_export the return from field_info_field and field_info_instance of an existing field, you can see how the field arrays are structured & use this structure when creating new ones.

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically create a taxonomy and attach a field to it, then create a content type and attach that taxonomy to it.

```
<?php
// Machine name for our custom node
define('NODE_NAME', 'the_node_machine_name');
// Machine name for our custom taxonomy
define('TAXONOMY_NAME', 'the_taxonomy_machine_name');
function module_install() {
  _create_taxonomy();
  _create_content_type();
}
/**
 * Create a taxonomy and attach a field to it.
 */
function _create_taxonomy() {
  $t = get_t();

  $term = new stdClass();
  $term->name = $t('Name');
  $term->machine_name = TAXONOMY_NAME;
  $term->description = $t('Description');
  $term->heirarchy = 1;
  $term->module = 'module_name';
  $term->weight = 1;
  taxonomy_vocabulary_save($term);
 // Create a field
 $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_tax_fieldname',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $t('Label')
  );
  field_create_field($field);
  // Attach the field to our taxonomy entity
  $instance = array(
      'field_name' => 'field_tax_fieldname',
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'bundle' => TAXONOMY_NAME,
      'label' => $t('Label'),
      'description' => $t('Description'),
      'required' => true,
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
        'weight' => 3
      )
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);

  // Done
}
/**
 * Create a content type and attach our created taxonomy to it.
 */
function _create_content_type() {
  $t = get_t();
  $node = array(
    'type' => NODE_NAME,
    'name' => $t('Name'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'description' => $t('Description'),
    'title_label' => $t('Title'),
    'custom' => TRUE
  );
  $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($node);
  node_add_body_field($content_type, $t('Article'));
  node_type_save($content_type);
  // Create a taxonomy field and use the taxonomy entity we created earlier
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_tax_name',
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',
    'label' => $t('Label'),
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        array(
          'vocabulary' => TAXONOMY_NAME,
          'parent' => 0
        )
      )
    )
  );
  field_create_field($field);
  // Add the field to the content type as a HTML select box.
  $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_tax_name',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => NODE_NAME,
    'label' => $t('Label'),
    'description' => '',
    'required' => TRUE,
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'weight' => -10,
    )
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);

  // Done
}
```

Comment: I had seen [this code](http://www.ambidev.com/add-taxonomy-with-custom-fields-programmaticaly/) before. This code attaches a field to a taxonomy vocab , I need to add a vocab to a content bundle

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JustAdam/3235992 check this link

Comment: thanks for the link , edit your answer using this link's info and I can vote it up.

Comment: vote up,This is good solution